# Sitecore Media Library restrict upload folder to specific file type / extension

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I am using Sitecore 6.6.0 and need a way to limit uploading specific files types (png, jpg, gif) etc. to folders within the Media Library

There is a plugin called [Media Library Policemen](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Media_Library_Policeman.aspx), but I am not allowed to use a module, plus it doesn't show the user an appropriate error message when he's trying to upload a forbidden file type.

I am kind of a Sitecore novice not sure what's the best way. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but theoretically, if you are able to add your own custom code, then Sitecore has the ability to assign folders to have Insert Rules OR Insert Options.  Insert Rules take an argument of Type which is really the assembly and the method name and allows you to dictate Insert rules for what can be inserted.  This allows you to write or use your own custom code.  Media Library Policeman has the source control available to use.  You should be able to look at the code for this and use or adapt it for your purposes.  Then you can use the Insert Rule to determine what can be added to the folder and remove the insert options.